# How can I unequivocally check if I'm working on a virtual machine?

Tags: windows, security, virtual-machine

I have read several articles explaining how to modify the system parameters to simulate a physical machine. You can change a bit of everything up to the CPUID even if obtained through assembler code by querying the right registers.

Some malware can know if they are working in a virtual machine and then, knowing it, try to access the physical machine.

Is there an unequivocal way to know if you are programmatically working in a virtual machine (Virtual Box, VMWare, Hyper-V, etc etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with the following PowerShell command (3 examples below)

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-CimInstance win32_computersystem | select Model

Model
-----
HP EliteDesk 800 G3 TWR


PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-CimInstance win32_computersystem -ComputerName ServerA | select Model

Model
-----
Virtual Machine


PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-CimInstance win32_computersystem -ComputerName ServerB | select Model

Model
-----
ProLiant DL380p Gen8
```

As you see, in the first command i checked my local machine, in second and third command i checked remote machines.

When the machine is virtual, it will return any of these values:

- `Virtual Machine` (Hyper-V)
- `VMware Virtual Platform` (VMWare)
- `VirtualBox` (VirtualBox)

anything else is quite safe to assume that it is physical, or anoter type of virtual machine that i did not list here.

Comment: The values you mention are changeable. This link explains how to do it, it's written for XP but I found the same thing for W10:
[link](https://msfn.org/board/topic/88477-virtual-machine-and-oem-license-for-windows/#comment-597316)

I think this applies to many other hardware parameters.

Comment: @Daniele hmmm... interesting. another way that comes to my mind is to check if there are any disks installed in the computer that are not virtual. `get-disk | ? { $_.Model -notlike '*virtual*' }` if this returns nothing, it means that there is no physical disk, which would suggest you are on a VM. if it returns something, you shouldn't be on a VM. Though, I don't know if this is unequivocal enough

Comment: He thinks it is also possible to change the cpuid. I therefore believe that changing the disk label from virtual to physical is not a big problem. In practice a virtual machine could reflect the hardware information of the host machine one by one.
I think we need to find a non-manipulable way to know for sure whether the program runs in a VM or not.
Perhaps by capturing something that all VMs have to have without the possibility of being changed. Someone suggests checking if in C: Windows System32 entries appear starting with VM as the mouse driver.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the very nature of a Virtual Machine, any method an attacker could use to determine whether it is running in a VM could be intercepted and countered by the system owner.

On the other hand, the attacker has the advantage because the system owner would have to guess and their next method in order to preemptively prevent the attack before it happened.

There is no way 100% guaranteed to unequivocally prove whether the machine you're running on is physical or virtual. It's a game of moving targets, cat and mouse.

Comment: What you say is true. Can there not be a 100% accurate method but a good method?

Comment: The "good" methods are the ones currently published, such as the PS command in the other answer, and others posted around the internet. What will work at one time or in one Hypervisor, though, is unlikely to work at another time and in another host for the reasons I've outlined in my own answer.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but now I don't know what answer to accept, given that from what has been said it seems both are correct.

Comment: Simon's answer is narrowly correct, in circumstances where the admin hasn't active worked to prevent VM detection. In most enterprises there is no effort to obfuscate the nature of the hardware. My answer is generally correct and applicable across all VMs and hypervisors, especially in cases where you're purchasing server time/space. While it's normal these days to assume you're running on a VM, only the administrators of the machines will know for certain the true nature of the hardware.

Answer (score 0):

I was just looking this up for a script I'm writing. The simplest thing I found is checking for a fan. VM's don't have them but physical machines do.

```
Get-CimInstance -Namespace root/CIMV2 -ClassName Win32_Fan
```